# Difference in using functions in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Lets say I have some component wo which I pass a function.

```
export default class SomeComp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    _someFunc = () => {
        return ...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View
                onLayout={this._someFunc()}
            />
```

OR

```
            <View
                onLayout={() => {this._someFunc()}}
            />

        )
    }
}
```

Where is the difference between `onLayout={this._someFunc()}` and `onLayout={() => {this._someFunc()}}`?

Comment: Did you mean difference between `onLayout={this._someFunc}` and `onLayout={() => {this._someFunc()}}`?

Comment: @bennygenel exactly. As I stated in the last sentence of the Q.

Comment: No. You didn't. First of all there is a difference between `onLayout={this._someFunc()}` and `onLayout={this._someFunc}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference depends really how and when `onLayout` is triggered.

- `onLayout={this._someFunc()}`

  Each time your component is rendered the `onLayout` prop will get the return value from the `this._someFunc()` function. In other words, the function will run on every render.
- `onLayout={() => {return this._someFunc()}}` or `onLayout={() => this._someFunc()}`

  Each time your component is rendered the `onLayout` prop will bind the reference to an anonymous function which contains the call to the `_someFunc()` function. The latter function doesn't get executed unless `onLayout` is somehow triggered.

---

For example, assume the following component:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {

  _someFunc = () => {
    return "bar";
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <A foo={this._someFunc()} />
        <B foo={() => {return this._someFunc()}} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const A = ({foo}) => {
  console.log(foo);  //prints "bar"
  return <div>A</div>;
}

const B = ({foo}) => {
  console.log(foo);  //prints the reference to _someFunc()
  console.log(foo());  //prints "bar"
  return <div>B</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In component `A` the `foo` prop will get the value of `"bar"`.

In component `B` the `foo` prop will be a reference to a function that you can later call. That function will in turn call `_someFunc` which will return `"bar"`. So if in component `B` you want to get the value, you need to call it with `this.props.foo()`.