# Pass props from Modal to other Component react navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I use [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/). I have a `TabNavigator`. Each `Tab` contains a `StackNavigator`. From one `StackNavigator`, it is possible to open a `Modal`. 
The `Modal` is opened when I click on a `Button` in a certain `Component`.

```
export default class CallModalComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    ...
    }

    ...

    render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
         return (
              <Button
               ....
               onPress={() => navigate("Modal")}/>
```

The in the `TabNav` registered screen `<MyModal />` is a stateful `Component`.
On close of the `Modal` I need the `state` of `<MyModal />` to be passed down to `<CallModalComponent />`.

The problem I am having is how that might work with `react navigation` in between... I know that I can use `redux` and send/retrieve it through the `global store`. But I wonder if its possible with only `react native`. 
Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I implemented the Code from answer

```
export default class CallModalComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    ...
    }

    ...
    onModalDismis(childVar) {
      console.log('modal is closing');
      console.log(childVar);
    }
    render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
         return (
              <Button
               ....
               onPress={(childVar) => navigate("Modal", {onModalDismis: this.onModalDismis()})}/>

// Then in your modal component

componentWillUnmount () {
    console.log('unmount');
    this.props.navigation.state.params.onModalDismis('here we go');
}
```

The following gets logged:
When the `Modal Component` is mounted I get:

`modal is closing`
`undefined`

Then, when I actually close the `Modal`, I get:

`unmount`

and then the error:

> Cannot read property of onModalDismiss of undefined.

I expected to be nothing logged on mounting of the `Modal`. And then, when I close the `Modal` I expected

`unmount`, `modal is closing` and `here we go` to be logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@bennygenel was very close. Added a little.

```
export default class CallModalComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    ...
    }

    ...
    onModalDismis(childVar) {
      console.log('modal is closing');
      console.log(childVar);
    }
    render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
         return (
              <Button
               ....
               onPress={() => navigate("Modal", {onModalDismis:(childVar) => this.onModalDismis(childVar)})}/>


// Then in your modal component
componentWillUnmount () {
    this.props.navigation.state.params.onModalDismis("some var");
}
```

The reason for using an `arrow function` is because it `binds()` the context of this https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56 *and* it only gets executed when `onModalDismis()` is called, and not the render of `<CallModalComponent/>`. [Difference in using functions in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192159/difference-in-using-functions-in-react-native)

Answer (score 6):

You can pass parameters to screens while navigating. This allows you to send a function to next screen and then you can initiate it when you want. More detail [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#navigate-Link-to-other-screens).

**Example**

```
export default class CallModalComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    ...
    }

    ...
    onModalDismis() {
      console.log('modal is closing');
    }
    render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
         return (
              <Button
               ....
               onPress={() => navigate("Modal", {onModalDismis: this.onModalDismis})}/>

// Then in your modal component

componentWillUnmount () {
    this.props.navigation.state.params.onModalDismis();
}
```

Comment: could you point me to the docs where I can read more about it?

Comment: I think you implemented the code wrong. Update your question with what you tried so far so I can have a better look

Comment: got it. Posted it as answer :) Thanks for your help!